# How to extract specific values in a string in informatica

Tags: expression, informatica

I need to extract the `(`, `)`, `-` and numbers from 0 to 9 from the input field phone number.

For eg., for input data : `(891)456-567A$rT67`

Output should be `(891)456-56767`

Answer (score 0):

can be done in below 2 steps -

```
v_ph_no = REG_REPLACE( in_ph_no,'[^0-9]','')` -- variable port that will replace everything but 0 to 9.
out_ph_no = '(' || substr(v_ph_no,1,3)||')' || substr (v_ph_no,4,3)||'-' || substr (v_ph_no,6) -- o/p port that will create ph no in desired format.
```

Explanation - first remove all unwanted characters and then format it in desired phone no format.